# Error making request to CodeCommit: Could not retrieve

Tags: aws-codecommit

I have pushed my last work to the repository, however, when I try to deploy, I get this error:

```
$ eb deploy myapp -v
Password:
INFO: Deploying code to myapp in region us-east-1
INFO: Getting version label from git with git-describe
INFO: Pushing local code to codecommit with git-push
INFO: Creating AppVersion app-V-2_0-90-g57b9-181013_080409
ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - "Error making request to CodeCommit: Could not retrieve 57b9246856a66460a7d04161d3f107f0553ac6ce (Service: AWSCodeCommit; Status Code: 400; Error Code: CommitIdDoesNotExistException; Request ID: 6d67928b-cea5-11e8-8620-d3a635300337)"
```

How can I get more details about that `InvalidParameterValueError` as in the error above?

What does `CommitIdDoesNotExistException` mean? I already pushed my latest commit.

Any idea?

Comment: I am also sttucked in this errror, someone please save me